# Init function in AngularJS that calls another function and that return undefined

Tags: angularjs

I'm really confused since I can't figure out why the varialbe fccDisplayName is "undefined". I created a function, made an api call, assigned a vlue to fccDisplayName; I get the value. But When this function is called within an Init function, I get an undefined.

I guess it has something to do with its "scope", but can't find why. Here I don't use $scope, but "Controller as".

Your help or any hint would be highly appreciated

```js
(function(){
  
  var app = angular.module('twitch', []); 
  
  app.controller('twitchController', ['$http', function($http){
    
    var twitchApi = 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/';
    var fccUrl = 'users/freecodecamp';
    var fccDisplayName;
    
    var getFcc = function(){
      $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: twitchApi+fccUrl
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
              fccDisplayName = response.data.display_name;
              fccBio = response.data.bio; 

          }, function errorCallback(response) {
              console.log(response);
      });
    }
    
    var init = function(){
   getFcc();
      console.log(fccDisplayName);
    }
    
    //We init the app
    init();
    
    
  }]);
  
})();
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
  <body ng-app="twitch">
    
<div ng-controller="twitchController as twitch"> 
      <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 item" id="freecodecamp">
          {{testAngular}}
          <h2>{{fccDisplayName}} Channel</h2>
      </div>
</div>    



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because of the **A** in Ajax.

Comment: Asynchronous you mean? But I checked the status that is 200, the call only returns a small result

Comment: Your console.log(fccDisplayName) runs before the $http get returns.  So fccDisplayName has not been set before you try to access it.  You can either access it in the then() function, or implement your own promise (I'd recommend $q for angular).

Comment: Thank you @dustmouse, you gave me the clear answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use `fccDisplayName` before your asynchronous service request is completed.  You need to perform your action inside of the `.then()` resolution of the request.

Once you've received the response, you need to bind it to the `this` context since you are using `controllerAs`.

```
var vm = this;

var getFcc = function(){
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: twitchApi+fccUrl
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        vm.fccDisplayName = response.data.display_name;
        fccBio = response.data.bio; 

        console.log(vm.fccDisplayName);
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
}

var init = function(){
    getFcc();
}
```

Update your html binding to point towards the `controllerAs` variable.

```
<div ng-controller="twitchController as twitch"> 
      <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 item" id="freecodecamp">
          {{testAngular}}
          <h2>{{twitch.fccDisplayName}} Channel</h2>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Many thanks, your answer and Dustmouse's explanation helped me a lot!

Comment: @millinet happy to help!